# bootstrap 3 row-same-height does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this sample all the columns share the same height:

http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

In my sample: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/ogrjML

The same css code does not produce the same output of same height columns.

What do I wrong?

I can not use Flexbox!

```
<div class="container">      
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-same-height row-full-height">

        <div style="background:orange;" class="col-xs-9 col-xs-height col-full-height">

            <div class="item">
                <div class="content">
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="background:red;" class="col-xs-3 col-xs-height col-full-height">
            <div class="item"><div class="content">test2</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some styles in the minimit example that are not included in bootstrap. You need to add the following to get the heights you desire:

```
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
.col-full-height {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEzOeq)

Comment: The column-xs-height with float:none has the effect of making my both bootstrap columns very narrow just as wide as the content is. When I remove the float:none both bootstrap columns have together a width of 100% again. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Pascal I see, you, need to declare table display for the parent row: `display:table;width:100%;`. Updated the answer and codepen.

Comment: ah so true Tony, that I did not think of that... of course every display: tabel-cell needs for the parent a display table also for the vertical centering :-) thanks a bunch!